# Obtener el parámetro que falla en un If

Tags: php, objeto, operadores

estoy tratando de verficar si por php puedo obtener cual de los parámetros en un if con multiples operaciones falla, si falla uno o mas de los operadores logicos detectar cual de ellos fallo.

```
<?php
$param1 = true;
$param2 = '0';
$param3 = 3;
$param4 = 'text';
if($param1 && true || 
    $param2 && '0' || 
    $param3 && 1 || 
    $param4 && 'text'){
        #Ejecucion correcta 
}else{
    #Determinar cual de los 4 parámetros fallo en la comprobación o si fueron varios.
}
?>
```

**Update**

verificando los comentarios creo php no tiene el alcance nativo para manejar la escenario, pero que la mejor manera seria hacer una funcion y ubicarla dentro del `else` así:

```
$r1 = ($param1 && true) ? true : false;
$r2 = ($param2 && '0') ? true : false;
$r3 = ($param3 && 1) ? true : false;
$r4 = ($param4 && 'text') ? true : false;

if($r1 || $r2 || $r3 || $r4 ){
    //Correcto
}else{
    #como puedo capturar las variables que fueron evaluadas y pasarlas por la funcion sin conocerlas(generico sera Variable o Array)
    #Funccion que evalua Cualquier variable del if e indica(retorna) en un array cual fallo
}
```

Comment: Creo que necesitarías volver a hacer las comparaciones, y guardar en una variable (una por cada comparación), según lo que obtengas como resultado de estas

Comment: Necesariamente tiene que ser un solo `if`, porque podrias hacer `if` anidados

Comment: bueno no conozco al 100% el alcance de php y queria saber si existe algo para lo que expongo sin necesidad de anidar mas if etc...

Comment: No, php no es capaz de hacer lo que ocupas, solo compara, te regresa el resultado y el garbage collector se encarga de limpiar variables y valores al terminar la ejecución del script

Comment: Y faltó mencionar que si usas el operador `||` y cualquiera de las comparaciones es true, siempre entrará en el `if` si lo que buscas es que todo se cumpla debes usar `&&`

Comment: ok esta claro lo del uso de || y && pero no puedo recrear un handler de error que tenga la capacidad de capturar los valores de un if y verificar cual dio false seria una funcion aparte pero generica.

Comment: tengo la idea pero no se plasmarlo en codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes evaluar de esta forma.

```
$r[0] = ($param1 == true) ? true : false;
$r[1] = ($param2 == '0') ? true : false;
$r[2] = ($param3 == 1) ? true : false;
$r[3] = ($param4 == 'text') ? true : false;

if($r[0] && $r[1] && $r[2] && $r[3] ){ //De acuerdo a comentario correcto
    //Correcto
}else{
    echo "El parámetro erróneo es el numero " . evaluar($r);
}

//Solo evalúa el primero erróneo para verificar mas retornar un array con los erróneos.
function evaluar($r){
    $max = sizeof($r);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if(!$r[$i]){return $i;}
    }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu idea eso acorta mas la distancia para el alcance de lo que vendría a hacer pero tengo algunas dudas de como hacer, acabo de agregar una actualizan en base a tu comentario.